# Adobe Acrobat X Pro - printing selected pages

Tags: printing, adobe-acrobat, selection

In previous versions, you could highlight several different pages and then print "selection".  This newer version does not seem to have this as an option when I go to my print screen.  Is this something I can change in preferences?

Answer (score 0):

You can still do this.

Just select all the pages on the thumbnail pane. Then right-click ([ctrl]-click on a Mac) on any of the selected pages, wait for the pop-up menu and select entry *'Print pages...'* from the pop-up.

But you are right: nobody understands why Adobe changed the way of basically every single task  you were used to get done from previous versions of Acrobat without any feelable improvement...  ;-(